# Delete Individual Items from Recycle Bin

Tags: powershell, recycle-bin

I am using Batch Delete using Powershell.

After batch delete, items are moved to recycle bin. `spWeb.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();` will delete all items from recycle bin. Instead, i want to remove only those items which i have batch deleted.

For that, i came across a command `spWeb.RecycleBin.Delete(Guid[] ids);` but i am missing something while implementing it. As a result i am getting error :

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: ids"
```

Following is the PowerShell Code used to achieve the same:

```
[Guid]$a = "fcfdc7d3-ef59-4988-b3e9-0ae7184c6c4f" (Sample GUID Present in recycle bin)
$deletions = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.Guid];
$deletions.Add($a)
$ArchiveWeb.RecycleBin.Delete($deletions.ToArray());
```

What i am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried calling Delete on the Item instead of on the collection?

Comment: Yes i did.In that case, it does not move to recycl But it takes too much time. I have to delete more than 1 lakh records at a go.So i performed Batch Delete.

Comment: I was thinking about the `SPRecycleBinItem` in the `RecycleBin`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're creating your guid in the correct manner? Try this:

```
$a = [System.Guid]"fcfdc7d3-ef59-4988-b3e9-0ae7184c6c4f"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure what is correct syntax for this. I will try this and update.

Comment: I am curious to know if this worked as I've never tried it myself?

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
   $sitecol = get-spsite “http://lmbsrhzwsp”  
    $deletions = new-object system.guid("fcfdc7d3-ef59-4988-b3e9-0ae7184c6c4f")   
    $sitecol.recyclebin.delete($guid)
```

[Clean Recycle Bin through Powershell in High Turnover Sharepoint Site](http://piyushmvp.com/2014/10/01/clean-recycle-bin-through-powershell-in-high-turnover-sharepoint-site/)